# PK font Lato-Italic-T1-TLF--base could not be created

Tags: fonts

I got the following error through using Miktex:

PK font Lato-Italic-T1-TLF--base could not be created.

Thank you for your comments in advance

```
\documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08emT\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\articletype{Article Type}%
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Run in the Miktex console (user mode) the task to refresh the font maps.

Comment: I used "refresh font map files" in Miktex console. But, again the error is not fixed.

Comment: Does it work if you add `\pdfmapfile{=lato.map}` to your document?